# How can I use this heroku php buildpack?

Tags: php, heroku, newrelic, buildpack

I'm trying to use https://github.com/taeram/heroku-buildpack-php-columbo so that I can have NEW RELIC working on my PHP install. No matter what I try, I always get the following error when pushing to heroku:

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 1.58 KiB, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Fetching Manifest
-----> Bundling Apache v2.2.24
tar: This does not look like a tar archive

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what may be going on here? I can successfully use https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php without issue. All I want to do is have NEW RELIC support along side php/apache.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the buildpack, it doesn't appear that `$BUILDPACK_S3_BUCKET` is set anywhere [when downloading Apache](https://github.com/taeram/heroku-buildpack-php-columbo/blob/master/bin/compile#L77), which obviously would result in a something (most likely an S3 XML error page) that `does not look like a tar archive`. I would either file an issue with this third-party buildpack's owner or fork and fix it yourself.